# non linear second order pde

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

I try to solve the following problem with zero luck. It seems like it can't solve all the different derivatives at once. Any suggestions?

```
d = 5*10^27; t0 = 0; t1 = 10^7; t2 = 2*10^7; Q = 1;`
pde = -d*D[n[r, t], {r, 2}] - (2*d)/r*D[n[r, t], r] + D[n[r, t], t] - 
      Q*DiracDelta[t - t0] - Q*DiracDelta[t - t1] == 0

ic = {n[r, 0] == 1/r, n[0, t] == t^-1.5}

sol[r_, t_] == DSolveValue[{pde, ic}, n[r, t], {r, t}]
```

Comment: What is the problem? Can you be more specific?

Comment: A DiracDelta only makes sense in an integral.

Comment: Have a look at `GreenFunction`

Comment: The problem is: `n[0, t] == t^(-3/2)`? .Using `laplace transform` to solve PDE we have to solve: `LaplaceTransform[1/t^(3/2), t, s]`.Try: `DSolveValue[{pde, n[r, 0] == 1/r, n[a, t] == 1/t^(3/2)}, 
 n[r, t], {r, t}]`.